# Insert UNICODE HAIRSPACE character into NSString

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, nsstringencoding

i'm trying to add a UNICODE character to NSString in this ways:

```
NSString *euFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u200A%@",self.eu];
```

or

```
unichar hairspaceChar = 0x200A; // hairspace symbol
NSString* hairSpace = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&hairspaceChar length:1];
NSString *euFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",hairSpace,self.eu];
```

But not results ... i try to find a solution but is making me crazy since 3 days.

I have try also to set the Font of UILabel that show the string like that:

```
bigFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
```

but no way, the HAIRSPACE is not supported.

here a screenshot if what i see, the HAIRSPACE suppose to be after the NUMBER 10 and BEFORE the '°' character.

[image]

Comment: how do you mean _no results_? have you logged the `NSString`? what does the console show? which font-set do you use to show the special character? does the font-set support it?

Comment: I'm using the default system apple font. No results i mean that is not adding any character inside the string.

Comment: the `Helvetica-Regular` and `Helvetica-Oblique` support it well, the other type of `Helvetica` does not (including the `Helvetica Neue`).

Comment: You can put raw unicode chars in a NSString in your source code. `NSString *test = @"I’m an  and we’re ★s"` works, so if you insert a hairspace it should work out of the box.

Comment: But where i can find a raw HAIRSPACE character? that's the point.

Comment: Found [here](http://la.remifa.so/unicode/unicode.php?start=2000&end=206F) and [here](http://www.publicsource.apple.com/source/X11proto/X11proto-57/fontconfig/fontconfig-2.8.0/fonts.conf.in), the HAIRSPACE in Helvetica is very small, in others Fonts is bigger. So that why is not possible to see a big difference. i will go for puntuaction space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: [Apple supported Characters](http://www.publicsource.apple.com/source/X11proto/X11proto-57/fontconfig/fontconfig-2.8.0/fonts.conf.in) and [row UTF8 Characters](http://la.remifa.so/unicode/unicode.php?start=2000&end=206F)

The HAIRSPACE is too small, i will go for Punctuation Space that is a bit Bigger and visible,

Answer (score 0):

If i try

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-\u200A-"]);
```

i get '- -'.

second example will not work.